# SFML help (Using the Sleep function in <Windows.h>)

Tags: c++, sleep, sfml

I need some help with my SFML/C++ code in Visual C++ 2010 Express Edition.  I am trying to get my text (livesLeft) to "You Win!" Before the program sleeps.  This is making the player know that he won.  But instead, the program goes right to sleep and changes the text right as it is closing, so you only see it change for a few milliseconds.  I can't even read it.

```
    bool play = true;
    bool win = false;
    bool touchFinish = false;

    int lives = 3;

    sf::Font arial;
    if(arial.loadFromFile("Fonts/arial.ttf") == 0)
    {
            return 1;
    }

    sf::Text livesLeft;
    livesLeft.setFont(arial);
    livesLeft.setCharacterSize(30);
    livesLeft.setString("Lives: ");
    livesLeft.setPosition(0, 0);
    livesLeft.setColor(sf::Color::White);

    sf::RectangleShape finish;
    finish.setSize(sf::Vector2f(200, 600));
    finish.setPosition(700, 0);
    finish.setFillColor(sf::Color::Green);
```

Those are my variables in use and this is my code where I'm trying to change the text:

```
    if(player.getGlobalBounds().intersects(finish.getGlobalBounds()))
    {
        livesLeft.setString("You Win!");
        touchFinish = true;
    }

    if(touchFinish)
    {
        win = true;
    }

    if(win)
    {
        Sleep(5000);
            play = false;
    }
```

I also forgot to add in that I do have the rendering at the end:

```
    window.clear();
    window.draw(livesLeft);
    window.draw(finish);
    window.draw(player);
    window.draw(obs1);
    window.draw(obs2);
    window.draw(obs3);
    window.draw(obs4);
    window.draw(obs5);
    window.draw(obs6);
    window.draw(obs7);
    window.draw(obs8);
    window.draw(obs9);
    window.draw(obs10);
    window.draw(obs11);
    window.draw(obs12);
    window.draw(obs13);
    window.display();
```

Comment: Because you need to update the screen, you set the string but you didn`t updated the screen with the new string. The data is there but you do a sleep and don't render it.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm a noob at this, how would you do that exactly, demonofnight?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is most likely due to the fact that you aren't calling the display method for you window.  Telling the text to change simply prepares the next framebuffer to display the new text, but because you never tell the window to update its display before sleeping, it never displays the new framebuffer.

[Here](http://sfml-dev.org/documentation/2.0/) is a quick example of a simple program using SFML.  Notice the window.display() method at the end of the main game loop.

You effectively want to be doing this:

```
if(win)
{
    window.display();
    Sleep(5000);
    play = false;
}
```

The reason why you need to update the display before hand again is because Sleep(5000); blocks the thread, essentially meaning that it sits at that call for 5000ms.  Also, if you want to keep the previous items on the screen, you'll want to redraw those before window.display(); as well, since these won't be in the next framebuffer.

Comment: I already have used that: window.clear();
  window.draw(livesLeft);
  window.draw(finish);
  window.draw(player);
  window.draw(obs1);
  window.draw(obs2);
  window.draw(obs3);
  window.draw(obs4);
  window.draw(obs5);
  window.draw(obs6);
  window.draw(obs7);
  window.draw(obs8);
  window.draw(obs9);
  window.draw(obs10);
  window.draw(obs11);
  window.draw(obs12);
  window.draw(obs13);
  window.display();

Comment: you need to place it specifically before the sleep method.  Sleep is a blocking call, meaning that it will not go past that point and never render.  Your method should effectively look like this:

if(win)
    {
        window.display();
        Sleep(5000);
            play = false;
    }

See my updates for better formatting.